# How can I pass fetched result as params of a component in router flux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx, react-native-router-flux

I'm trying to pass params within component of a tab bar in react native using router flux.What I've done is fetched result is passed as params within a component inside tab bar.Following is my code

**Home.js**

```
fetch(GLOBAL.COURSES)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
                this.setState({
                    cats: responseData.data,
                    vdo: responseData.video,
                    isLoading: false
                })
            })

..
...
                     <Tabs>
                        <Tab
                            heading="Courses"
                        >
                            <Courses cats={this.state.cats} />
                        </Tab>
                     ...
                       ...
                  </Tabs>
```

And within `Courses` page I'm trying to get this props as

```
 {this.props.cats.map(category =>

                           <View>
                           ....
                           ....
                           </View>
)}
```

I'm getting `undefined is not an object evaluating this.props.cats.map`.What is the mistake in my code please help.

Comment: The problem is that fetching data takes time. So at least the first render of `<Courses>` has an undefined `cats` prop. Try to control it like `{this.props.cats && this.props.cats.map(category...`

Comment: you don't need to do that if your initial state is defined as an empty array.

Comment: @SubhenduKundu true, but he's actually trying to render from props, not from state

Comment: So the render method is called after the constructor called. So there you have an empty array. this.props.cats will have an empty array. And renders the component with an empty array. Then setState gets called with bunch of data of array, and renders method gets called again, that time this.props.cats will have a data full of array.

Comment: Man, we're talking about the same thing

Comment: Perfect, then you don't need to do the check. Cause array.map works with empty array. And there is no way it will be undefined.

Answer (score 2):

So first time your component render, `this.state.cats` is undefined.

What you can do with your code is:

1. wrap your fetch call in async call, i.e., a promise. For example,

```js
//function
const fetchCats = async () => {
  const responseData = await fetch(GLOBAL.COURSES)
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((responseDataSuccess) => {
          return responseDataSuccess;
  });
  this.setState({
     cats: responseData.data,
     vdo: responseData.video,
     isLoading: false
  });
}
```

Or

2. to your component `<Courses />` you can do such that it does not render until cars state has required value and also it will be a good practice to initialize `this.state = { cars: [] }`

```js
import { get } from 'lodash';
// a utility set for javascript

<Tabs>
  <Tab heading="Courses" >
  {get(this.state, cats) && <Courses cats={this.state.cats} />}
  </Tab>
                     ...
                       ...
</Tabs>
```

P.S. focus on your state management and you are good to go.

Comment: kudos. This helps @Sania

Comment: You don't really need to wrap it with async cause @anu is calling the setState only after the .then() method is called. But 2nd part of your answer is important. :-)

Answer (score 0):

So the render method is called after the constructor called. So there you have an empty array. this.props.cats will have an empty array. And renders the component with an empty array. Then setState gets called with bunch of data of array, and renders method gets called again, that time this.props.cats will have a data full of array.
Umm make sure you have initial state defined as

```
state = {
 cats = []
....
}
or 
this.state = {
 cats = []
....
}
```

Also do a console.log `responseData.data` if it returning an array.

Comment: Yes I've consoled th result.But nothing is rendered

Comment: What's the response of `responseData.data`?  Is it an array?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to loop over your `cat` array without having yet received the response from your service.

A common pattern is to display a loading spinner while you are waiting for the service response.

```
<Tab heading="Courses">
  {!this.state.isLoading && (<Courses cats={this.state.cats} />)}
  {this.state.isLoading && "Loading..."}
</Tab>
```

Comment: `Text strings must be rendered within text component`.I removed this `{this.state.isLoading && "Loading..."}` from your code.Now nothing is coming.

Comment: The error is quite explicit. Try with `{this.state.isLoading && (<span>Loading...</span>)}` or replace it by whatever component you want to display while loading data.